# Elasticsearch Date Histogram Aggregation - How to force max (most resent) full interval

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to return data bucketed by term and then by a date interval from ElasticSearch using `elasticsearch_dsl`. The **interval is parameterized**, and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to force ElasticSearch to return up to the **last full interval** (based on a date range) filling in missing intervals with zeros.

I am already using `min_doc_count=0` and `extended_bounds.min` in the aggregation, and that takes care of the start of the range, but can't figure out how to specify `extended_bounds.max` such that it doesn't grab most recent partial interval.

Here's relevant bit of code I have so far:

```
from_period = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=lookback_in_days))

date_range_max = "now"
if interval in FULL_INTERVALS:
    # round down by interval
    date_range_max += "/" + (interval[:1].upper() if interval == 'month' else interval[:1])
else:
    # round down by time unit
    temp = re.split(PARTIAL_INTERVAL_PATTERN, interval)
    ## e.g. for interval = '3d', temp will have ['', '3', 'd', '']
    date_range_max += "/" + temp[2]

s = ES_Search(doc_type='message', index=config['ES_INDEX_NAME']) \
    .using(client) \
    .query('match', foo=bar) \
    .filter('range',
            **{
                "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": from_period,
                    "lt": date_range_max
                }
            }
    )

for name in score_names:
    s.aggs.bucket(name, 'terms', field='meta.{}.value.keyword'.format(name))
    s.aggs[name].bucket(
        'interval_buckets',
        'date_histogram',
        field='@timestamp', interval=interval,
        format='YYYY-MM-dd', time_zone=time_zone,

        # set a "hard" start/end dates to make sure uniform earliest/latest bucket, and include empty buckets
        min_doc_count=0,
        extended_bounds={
            "min": from_period.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            "max": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        }
    )
```

Is there a way to specify `extended_bounds.max` such that `Elasticsearch` will do the calculation based on `filter`, or do I have to do manual calculation of the date to use in `extended_bounds.max`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no way to avoid manual calculation.

I tried using a separate query, which actually worked, but made me realize that upper bound of `range` filtering doesn't work for intervals that are multiples (e.g. 3d, 2w, etc.) since you can only truncate by one unit (e.g. /d, /w, etc.)